# Convert HTML entities inside <code> tag to display on web site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Good day,

I'm writing some HTML/CSS code examples on a web site. I'm using the `<code>` element to mark out my examples.

I'm trying to:

1. Convert all HTML-tags inside my `<code>` blocks to be displayed on my web site
2. Make my examples beautiful with syntax highlighting and maybe even auto indent

I have tried PrismJS and Highlighter.JS but I cannot get any of them to convert the HTML tags. Are you forced to make it server side? And if so are there any PHP-examples or tools for this that works fine with any of the JS-libraries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Ace editor (and put into read only mode) http://ace.c9.io, example website where i have done a similar thing: http://www.rsps.net/rsps-callback-voting

Comment: Wow! ACE was impressive. But it feels a bit overkill for my 10 row examples? Or is that the only way?

Comment: Its a simple way that i like to do this, theres probably lower profile ones, but if it does the job right then its a good way to go, if you put the code into a textarea then get Ace editor to push the content to the code tag, this will then work how you want it too, you can initialise multiple Ace instances so its not much to do to get this work how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you might do a simple trick to display html and css codes without and  `tag 
You might simply but the text inside a input within the code
Then you might simply style it and give it custom background and everything also it will be easy for the user to copy it but make sure to right the code you want to display inside the html code not on the rendered page or it will not be displayed to the users like this`

```
<input type="text" name="html_test_code">whatever code here</input>
```

And then the styling of sytax might be done using js easily

Comment: Thanks! It worked to write it inside a <textarea> tag as well. From what I see up till now this is the best solution even though I don't really like it...

It would be so nice if it was possible to just use <code> tags and replace all tags inside before it was displayed for the user

Comment: You might do something dynamic like changing the tag <code> with <input> using javascript or jqueey put might you please vote for me up cause i need reptution